# Unique equivalence class confusion

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, equivalence-relations

A generic equivalence class for a relation with which I am working is:

$[x]=\left\{y\in\mathbb{Z} | x^3 \equiv y^3 \text{mod}4\right\}$

I thought at first that the unique equivalence classes were:

$[0]=\left\{y\in\mathbb{Z} | 0 \equiv y^3 \text{mod}4\right\}$

$[1]=\left\{y\in\mathbb{Z} | 1 \equiv y^3 \text{mod}4\right\}$

$[2]=\left\{y\in\mathbb{Z} | 8 \equiv y^3 \text{mod}4\right\}$

$[3]=\left\{y\in\mathbb{Z} | 27 \equiv y^3 \text{mod}4\right\}$

But I believe that $[0]=[2]$. Is it true that the only unique classes are $[0], [1]$ and $[3]$?

Comment: Yes, you got it. What are you puzzled by?

Comment: @bof I wasn't sure if the classes I found were comprehensive or how I might go about showing that. (I don't have to show that, but I am curious.)

Comment: With all congruences taken modulo $4$: If $y\equiv0$ then $y^3\equiv0^3\equiv0;$ if $y\equiv1$ then $y^3\equiv1^3\equiv1;$ if $y\equiv2$ then $y^3\equiv2^3\equiv0;$ if $y\equiv3$ then $y^3\equiv3^3\equiv3.$ So the three equivalence classes are $\{y:y\equiv1\}$ and $\{y:y\equiv3$ and $\{y:y\equiv0\text{ or }1\}.$ But it seems to me you had already worked that out. Basically, the work just consists of seeing that $0^3\equiv2^3\equiv0$ and $1^3\equiv1$ and $3^3\equiv3.$

Comment: $8\equiv 0 \pmod 4.$......